# Location of GACUTIL in Windows server 2008 production box

Tags: .net, gac, gacutil

I have a production box (Windows Server 2008) where no visual studio is installed. Can I use GACUTIL there...If so where can i find the gacutil exe in that machine

Answer (score 1):

It does not exit on the production box, because it gets installed with Visual Studio or the win SDK only. Your bestbet is use a powershell script such as [link text](http://weblogs.asp.net/adweigert/archive/2008/10/31/powershell-install-gac-gacutil-for-powershell.aspx)